# How to do Infinite Scroll pagination with grouped elements in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to do **Infinite Scroll** pagination with grouped elements. What I did was to integrate a [flutter package to do pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pagewise)

But I have a list of elements which are grouped (by date). Is it possible to group elements in this situation? Here is my code implementing a grouped ListView:

```dart
return Container(
  color: Colors.grey[200],
    child: GroupedListView<dynamic, dynamic>(
    separator: Divider(height: 0.0, color: Colors.grey[200]),
    sort: false,
    elements: txs,
    groupSeparatorBuilder: (value) {
      ...
    },
  )
);
```

the code above is from this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)

and the package I would like to use to do Infinate Scroll pagination:

```dart
return PagewiseListView<PostModel>(
  pageSize: PAGE_SIZE,
  itemBuilder: this._itemBuilder,
  pageFuture: (pageIndex) => BackendService.getPosts(
    (PAGE_SIZE * pageIndex) + 1, PAGE_SIZE * (pageIndex + 1)
  )
);
```

update: here is what i want to do but with paginaton, like you see in the picture the elements are grouped by date.

[image]

Comment: I can't understand.
What do you need exactly?

Comment: i want to do pagination with elements which should be grouped, how can i do that?

Comment: i have edited the question @e200, with the screenshot on what the ui should be once the pagination is integrated, hope it helps